# How to stream the /camera/rgb/image_color from Kinect to another workstation

Tags: ros, turtlebot, video, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a laptop connected to a Turtlebot with a Kinect. I have been able to get the live video of the kinect through rviz. I also am able to connect from another machine to the laptop via ssh. However, I have not been able to get the video from the kinect displayed on the other machine. When i try this via ssh

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color

(image_color:10277): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Is there anyway I can access the /camera/rgb/image_color using a vlc player or something of that sort?

Thanks,
Ian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61871/how-to-stream-the-/camera/rgb/image_color-from-kinect-to-another-workstation/) by [mcculloughi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4794/mcculloughi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The other computer should be able to connect on other ports, ssh only forwards one port. Are the two machines on the same network? You should create a listener that knows the other ros_master_uri. Perhaps vlc with the correct ip and port number also works.
See also: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1